# Is there any way to return beveled UI elements to Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I mean - is it possible to make buttons and scrollbars (etc) look like 3D objects (like they looked in pre-8 versions) and return back UI element shadows?

Comment: use a 3rd party theme like this one: http://damonkeyoncrack.deviantart.com/art/Aero7-V2-for-Windows-8-8-1-10-TP-429412929

Comment: @magicandre1981, I just can't get it working. I've done what is described in readme.txt, and nothing has changed.

Comment: have you patched the UXTheme files?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I've done all what's described in the readme, including patching that files.

Comment: post a picture of what you currently see. Maybe I can help you

Comment: @magicandre1981, http://i.imgur.com/RRDW7Fx.png and btw, it says that symbols are no longer necessary.

Comment: you can't read. **"Copy files in theme win8 or theme 8.1 (depending on what you are running) folder to C:/Windows/Resources/Themes."** You copied the complete extracted folder and not only the theme data.

Comment: @magicandre1981, well, the installation instruction is written remarkably poorly. "Copy files in theme folder to C:\Windows\Resources\Themes"

Comment: @magicandre1981, http://i.imgur.com/7Gh5kE2.png Now what?

Comment: have you patched the uxtheme files or installed this in-memory patcher? http://uxstyle.com/

Comment: @magicandre1981, I don't see anything in readme that says that I should (and how to do that).

Comment: again, you don't read correctly: "Requirements- Windows 8, 8.1, or 10 TP, **UXTheme Patcher**"

Comment: @magicandre1981, that's because readme is a mess. I give up.

Comment: this is so simply and took only 2 minutes. I posted the steps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps to get it working.

1. Install [UxStyle](http://uxstyle.com/), to patch the uxtheme DLLs in memory
2. [download and extract the theme](http://damonkeyoncrack.deviantart.com/art/Aero7-V2-for-Windows-8-8-1-10-TP-429412929)
3. if you use Windows 8, copy the content of `aero7_v2_for_windows_8_8_1_10_tp_by_damonkeyoncrack-d73nt4x\aero7\theme win8\chromed navbar`, if you use Windows 8.1, copy the content of `D:\Daten\Downloads\aero7_v2_for_windows_8_8_1_10_tp_by_damonkeyoncrack-d73nt4x\aero7\theme 8.1\chromed navbar` to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes`
4. go to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes`, double click on `aero7.theme` file to apply the theme
5. (optional) install [Aero Glass mod](http://glass8.eu/), to get the transparency back.

If you follow the steps you get this:

[image]